# Массовое обновление ACF полей всех таксономий

Tags: wordpress, база-данных, acf, tag

Есть много записей. В них много категорий и много тегов. Добавил поля для каждой таксономии записи плагином ACF с текстами по умолчанию. Вопрос заключается в том, что нет желания перелистыва все по 2 тысячи таксономий (категории и теги), нажимать кнопку "Обновить", чтобы поля записались в бд. Возможно есть метод, который применит все поля для таксономий с одной перезагрузкой страницы?

Скрин с количеством тегов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин кнопки обновить настройки в бд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACF-поля терминов хранятся в обычной term_meta. Выполняете скрипт примерно такой:

```
$terms = get_terms(
    [
        'taxonomy'   => 'your-taxonomy',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ]
);

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        update_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'your_acf_field_name', 'value' );
    }
}
```

Но для вашего примера логично сделать настройки темы или плагина, где у вас будет title по умолчанию.

Либо же включите Yoast SEO и добавьте туда несколько переменых и используйте на здоровье готовый функционал и не придумывайте велосипед)

Comment: отлично. Спасибо ^^